# Outliner filter or sort by object type?

Tags: objects, outliner

Is there anyway to filter by object types not separated by layers? For example, i have an imported scene with many cameras, and I would like to see all cameras in now list.

Comment: if you select one camera, and go to the outliner you can select same types. It gives a list of camera's

Comment: Thanks gladys. That makes sense, although not as intuitive as I would like

Answer (score 1):

1. In *3d View* **select 1 object** of your desired type (Camera, Light, Mesh etc.)
2. Go to the *Outliner* and select **Same Types** from the dropdown menu

This will display all objects in your scene based on the current selection. E.g. When a camera is selected, the outliner will display all available cameras in your scene:

[image]

Comment: I think it would be helpful to explain *how* they can select the same types from the outliner.